# Memory Boundaries in SRAM

Tags: arm, memory, dma, cortex-m4, cortex-m0

I am trying to use the GPDMA which is present in LPC43XX parts.

The [UM10503](https://studio.segger.com/packages/LPC4300/CMSIS/Documents/UM10503.pdf) data sheet constantly warns about memory boundaries (datasheet section 21): basically it says that you don't want to try a burst across a memory boundary otherwise "the transfer will be split into two AHB transactions".

The problem is that I don't understand what these memory boundaries are.

Here's some information (datasheet section 3):

**RAM sections:**

[image: Screenshot from datasheet showing RAM sections]

**Memory Map**

[image: Screenshot from datasheet showing memory map]

Are the memory boundaries those solid lines? If so, they seem to be too wide for me.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the ARM AMBA 5 AHB Protocol Specification, section 3.5:

> Masters must not attempt to start an incrementing burst that crosses a 1KB address boundary.

<sub>Note that in the AXI specification they changed this to a 4K boundary</sub>

Comment: OK so my DMA app should not write more than 1024 bytes right? (provided that the starting address is 1KB aligned)

Comment: From your error message I read that the system splits your transaction into 2 or more AHB transactions. So looks like it is possible/allowed to send more than 1K. The question is which one gives the best throughput, you splitting the transaction or the system. My gut feeling is that the latter is faster.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think you're right. Will update this post if I discover something else.